# Textchanges only visible after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, lifecycle, page-lifecycle

I have a method that changes the text of the controls on my site.
These changes should be visible right when the user loads the page.
But the changes are first visible after the next postback.

I tried to call it in `Page_PreInit`, `Page_Init`, `Page_PreLoad` and and all the other methods described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
But none of them worked.

Some code:
The class with the methods: (partly)

```
    namespace MyNamespace {
        public class ControlTextCorrection {

            Page _page;

            public ControlTextCorrection(Page page) {
                _page = page;
            }

            public void Correct() {
                HtmlEncodeControls(_page);
            }

            private void HtmlEncodeControls(Page page) {
                Control control = (Control)page;
                HtmlEncodeControls(control);
            }

            private void HtmlEncodeControls(Control parentControl) {
                if (!parentControl.HasControls()) {
                    return;
                }
                foreach (Control control in parentControl.Controls) {
                    if (control.HasControls()) {
                        HtmlEncodeControls(control);
                    }
                    if (control is Label) {
                        Label label = (Label)control;
                        label.Text = HtmlTextCorrection(label.Text);
                    }
                    else if (control is CheckBox) {
                        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)control;
                        checkBox.Text = HtmlTextCorrection(checkBox.Text);
                    }
                    //Correction for more controls...
                }
            }

            protected string HtmlTextCorrection(string text) {
                bool encode = true;
                while (encode) {
                    string newText = _page.Server.HtmlDecode(text);
                    if (newText == text) {
                        encode = false;
                    }
                    text = newText;
                }
                text = _page.Server.HtmlEncode(text);
                return text;
            }
        }
    }
```

Example for calling the method:

```
    protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ControlTextCorrection correction = new ControlTextCorrection(this.Page);
        correction.Correct();
    }
```

So, where (*when*) should i call it so that the changes are visible at the first sight of the site?

Comment: Can you show us the markup for the controls (at least some of them) and the method you are talking about?

Comment: I think you might have to show the code you have tried.

Comment: _What_ have you tried? How should we know what's wrong if we don't see the code?

Comment: Ok, i'll post some, wait a minute...

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok i added some code to my question.

Comment: What happens if you perform the call in Page_Load event?

Comment: @Aschratt The same behavior as described in the question.